# Get count of related items and subtract that from attribute in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I've got three models and I'm trying to simplify my queries a bit.

I'm trying to return a list of `Course` objects that have not been completely registered/paid for. So I need to get a count of the `Payment` objects, and then see if that is equal to the total `available_seats` on a `Course` object.

I've got a `Payment`, `Course`, and `Registration` model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    registration = models.ForeignKey(Registration, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_refunded = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Course(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    seat_count = models.IntegerField()

class Registration(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

I only want to consider a seat 'taken' if a `Payment` has been made - so a count of `Payment` for a given `Course` is what I'm trying to get.

I was trying something like this:

```
    payments = (
        Payment.objects.filter(
            registration__course__id=OuterRef("pk"), is_refunded=False
        ).values("pk")
        # .annotate(
        #     total_seats_available=F("registration__course__seat_count")
        #     - Count("registration")
        # )
        # .values("total_seats_available")
    )
    courses = (
        Course.objects.filter(id__in=course_ids)
        .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "registration_set",
                queryset=Registration.objects.prefetch_related(
                    "payment_set"
                ),
            )
        )
        .annotate(
            paid_seats=Case(
                When(
                    Exists(payments),
                    then=Count(payments),
                ),
                default=None,
            ),
            has_available_seats=Case(
                # No Payment have been recorded
                When(paid_seats=None, then=Value(True)),
                # Payment exist and total_seats_available should calc
                When(paid_seats__gt=0, then=Value(True)),
                # Default to False
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField(),
            ),
        )
        .filter(has_available_seats=True)
    )
```

Currently this returns a count of the Payment objects and if it's greater than 0, considers the course to have available seats.

What is the best way to perform the logic to have the `Course` annotate a value that is the `seat_count - payments` to get an accurate idea of 'how many' seats are actually available?

Where should that logic live? I left in some logic I had commented out that was not working. I can't seem to get this quite right.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with `F()` expressions:

```
    payments = (
        Payment.objects.filter(
            registration__course__id=OuterRef("pk"), is_refunded=False
        ).values("pk")
    )
    courses = (
        Course.objects.filter(id__in=course_ids)
        .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "registration_set",
                queryset=Registration.objects.prefetch_related(
                    "payment_set"
                ),
            )
        )
        .annotate(
            paid_seats=Case(
                When(
                    Exists(payments),
                    then=Count(payments),
                ),
                default=None,
            ),
            available_seats=Case(
                When(Exists(payments), then=F('seat_count')-F('paid_seats'),
                default=F('seat_count'),
                output_field=IntegerField(),
            ),
            has_available_seats=Case(
                When(available_seats__gte=0, then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BooleanField(),
            ),
        )
        .filter(has_available_seats=True)
    )
```